# Converting String Type To Windows.UI.Color In Windows Universal App

Tags: c#, xml, uwp, windows-10-universal, uwp-xaml

I'm trying to make a program to parse xml files with predefined format, and add some UI controls to my MainPage in Windows Universal Application.

In some part, I need to specify the background color of my TextBlocks in related xml file, so I'm looking for a way to convert string attribute, read from xml and convert it to Windows.UI.Color corresponding value.

here is my xml file and my C# code to add control

xml :

```
<test-unit name ="FOG_LAMP"  text ="Fog Lamp"  mode ="DIG_IN" color="ORANGE"/>
```

C#:

```
public void AddNewTextBlock(String Name, String Text, String Color)
{
    TextBlock NewTextBlock = new TextBlock();
    NewTextBlock.Name = Name;
    NewTextBlock.Text = Text;
    NewTextBlock.FontSize = 24;
    myGrid.Children.Add(NewTextBlock);
}
```

Thanks For Help

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use [`XamlBindingHelper`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.markup.xamlbindinghelper) to convert the `string` value to `Color` -

```
var color = (Color)XamlBindingHelper.ConvertValue(typeof(Color), "ORANGE");
var brush = new SolidColorBrush(color);
NewTextBlock.Foreground = brush;
```

Comment: @D.Ghiaseddin, if it works for you, please accept it as the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Use [Colors Helper](https://learn.microsoft.com/windows/uwpcommunitytoolkit/helpers/colors) of UWPCommunityToolkit.

```
Color redColor = "Red".ToColor();
Color redColor = ColorHelper.ToColor("#ff3a4ab0");    //For Alpha code
```

Comment: @Hetal Updated the link