# XamlBindingHelper Class

Tags: c#, uwp, uwp-xaml, xbind

Can somebody provide an overview for use of the `XamlBindingHelper` class with examples? Specifically the `GetDataTemplateComponent` and `SetDataTemplateComponent` method.

Comment: Check this: https://www.bing.com/search?q=XamlBindingHelper+&qs=n&form=QBRE&sp=-1&pq=xamlbindinghelper+&sc=2-18&sk=&cvid=1B14A2054D2A4BE795829F474983B627

Comment: @QualityCatalyst I did, I didn't find examples.

Comment: As the document said **This method is for use in code that is generated by the XAML compiler.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the official [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.markup.xamlbindinghelper), it says

> This class is for use in code that is generated by the XAML compiler.

This tells me that I should be able to find some reference of it in code-generated classes (`.g.cs`) by `x:Bind`, given there's not a single thread on the Internet that explains what exactly it does.

So I created a test UWP project with a `ListView`, and inside its `ItemTemplate` I threw in some `x:Bind` with `x:Phase`. After I compiled the project, I found some of its methods used inside my `MainPage.g.cs` -

**XamlBindingHelper.ConvertValue**

```
public static void Set_Windows_UI_Xaml_Controls_ItemsControl_ItemsSource(global::Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.ItemsControl obj, global::System.Object value, string targetNullValue)
{
    if (value == null && targetNullValue != null)
    {
        value = (global::System.Object) global::Windows.UI.Xaml.Markup.XamlBindingHelper.ConvertValue(typeof(global::System.Object), targetNullValue);
    }
    obj.ItemsSource = value;
}
```

Apparently the `XamlBindingHelper.ConvertValue` method is for converting values. I knew this already, as I used it in [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44860768/converting-string-type-to-windows-ui-color-in-windows-universal-app/44861070#44861070) of my recent answers on SO.

---

**XamlBindingHelper.SuspendRendering** & **XamlBindingHelper.ResumeRendering**

```
public int ProcessBindings(global::Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.ContainerContentChangingEventArgs args)
{
    int nextPhase = -1;
    switch(args.Phase)
    {
        case 0:
            nextPhase = 1;
            this.SetDataRoot(args.Item);
            if (!removedDataContextHandler)
            {
                removedDataContextHandler = true;
                ((global::Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.StackPanel)args.ItemContainer.ContentTemplateRoot).DataContextChanged -= this.DataContextChangedHandler;
            }
            this.initialized = true;
            break;
        case 1:
            global::Windows.UI.Xaml.Markup.XamlBindingHelper.ResumeRendering(this.obj4);
            nextPhase = -1;
            break;
    }
    this.Update_((global::System.String) args.Item, 1 << (int)args.Phase);
    return nextPhase;
}

public void ResetTemplate()
{
    this.bindingsTracking.ReleaseAllListeners();
    global::Windows.UI.Xaml.Markup.XamlBindingHelper.SuspendRendering(this.obj4);
}
```

`XamlBindingHelper.SuspendRendering` & `XamlBindingHelper.ResumeRendering` look very interesting. They seem to be the key functions to enable `ListView`/`GridView`'s incremental item rendering which helps improve the overall panning/scrolling experience.

So apart from `x:DeferLoadingStrategy` and `x:Load`(*Creators Update*), they are something else that could be used to improve your app performance.

---

**IDataTemplateComponent** & **IDataTemplateExtension**

However, I couldn't find anything related to `GetDataTemplateComponent` and `SetDataTemplateComponent`. I even tried to manually set this attached property in XAML but the *get* method always returned `null`.

And here's the interesting bit. I later found this piece of code in the generated class.

```
case 2: // MainPage.xaml line 13
    {                    
        global::Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Grid element2 = (global::Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Grid)target;
        MainPage_obj2_Bindings bindings = new MainPage_obj2_Bindings();
        returnValue = bindings;
        bindings.SetDataRoot(element2.DataContext);
        element2.DataContextChanged += bindings.DataContextChangedHandler;
        global::Windows.UI.Xaml.DataTemplate.SetExtensionInstance(element2, bindings);
    }
    break;
```

The method `DataTemplate.SetExtensionInstance` looks very similar to `XamlBindingHelper.SetDataTemplateComponent`. It takes `element2` which is the root `Grid` inside the `ItemTemplate` of my `ListView`, and an [`IDataTemplateExtension`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.idatatemplateextension); where the latter takes an element and an [`IDataTemplateComponent`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.markup.idatatemplatecomponent). If you have a look at their definitions, their functionalities are very similar, which makes me think if `DataTemplate.SetExtensionInstance` is the replacement of `XamlBindingHelper.SetDataTemplateComponent`? I'd love to know if otherwise.

Unlike `IDataTemplateComponent`, you *can* get an instance of the `IDataTemplateExtension` in your code -

```
var firstItemContainer = (ListViewItem)MyListView.ContainerFromIndex(0);
var rootGrid = (Grid)firstItemContainer?.ContentTemplateRoot;
var dataTemplateEx = DataTemplate.GetExtensionInstance(rootGrid);
```

In my case, the `dataTemplateEx` is an instance of another generated class called `MainPage_obj2_Bindings`, where you have access to methods like `ResetTemplate` and `ProcessBindings`.

I assume they could be helpful if you were to build your own custom list controls, but other than that I just can't see why you would ever need them.

Comment: Thank you, that was a great overview.

Comment: You are very welcome. I learnt a few things from answering it too. :)